# check if a comment was made by a registered user

Tags: comments, conditional-tags

Is there any *Conditional Tag* to check whether a comment is made by registered user or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$comment = get_comment( $CommentID );
$commentatorID = $comment->user_id;
  if ($commentatorID > 0 ) {
     //Comment made by registered user, do stuff
  }
```

From the codex [`get_comment()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment), about the *return* value of `user_id`:

> **user_id**
>    (integer) The comment author's ID if he is registered (0 otherwise)

Comment: Thank you...
I'm so focused searching on conditional tags that I didn't realize that there's such a workaround for it.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can create your own conditional tag, this is pretty much using what @Abhik suggested:

**Code:**

```
function is_comment_by_registered_user( $comment_ID = 0 ) {
    if ( empty( $comment_ID ) )
        $comment_ID = get_comment_ID();

    $comment = get_comment( $comment_ID );
    $comment_user_id = $comment->user_id;

    if ( $comment_user_id > 0 ) :
        return true;
    else :
        return false;
    endif;
}
```

*Note:* untested